# How to handle server side certificate in https calls with angular 5

Tags: angular, api, ssl

I deployed an Angular 5 + Symfony(api) on apache2(ubuntu). The access to both is https

```
https://app-name.my.domain
https://app-api-name.my.domain
```

The connection works fine, the issue is when I have to access in a fresh browser(previously not connected or installed). Obviously I access to app-name site and add the certificate exception but when angular makes a request to the api returns with an error. The issue is that the certificate(not added yet) is self signed and cannot be trusted, etc. 
After that I access my app-api-name site add the certificate return to app-name site and all works fine!

My Question is how can I grant https access to the api with out making that process(At company there are a lot of computers and I don't want to to this).

The ideal workflow would be something like:

1. The user connects to the app-name site
2. If is the first time add the certificate.
3. The user work in the app-name site.(with out adding that certificate too)

Comment: You'd need a wildcard SSL cert that is able to handle multiple domains that isn't self-signed.

Comment: I searched acording to your recomendation but can´t find a free one. Do you have any reference?

Comment: There used to be some free SSL cert services out there, but I doubt if you'll be able to find a credible one for a wildcard cert for free.